# Controlling two PDF viewrs with a single presenter or mouse wheel

Tags: linux, presentations, input-device, logitech-presenter

I've been living on the CLI for 5 years now. 
However, now and then comes a situation when I have to use other input devices.

Specifically, I am planing on giving a talk (beamer latex) and the presentation must be opened with adobe reader because of animations. However, I'd like to have my private notes on my notebook's screen. This can be e.g. mupdf or any other viewer.

I would like to be able to switch slides on both readers at the same time using a Logitech R500 presenter or alternatively, a mouse wheel. I'm guessing somebody with more knowledge then I knows how something like this might be achieved?

I've also thought about producing the beamer file with notes and than using a multi-head across two displays and a virtual desktop, but this has shown instability and I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Any information would be welcome.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations

Comment: Non of those apply, I'm looking to use adobe + something else on linux. Not on windows or osx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with writing a small python script, it should be rather straightforward to write one which reacts to `PageUp` and `PageDown` by running `xdotool` to send the respective key to two other windows.